# libavcodec determine codec features

Tags: ffmpeg, libavcodec

Is there a way to programmatically determine features of a codec?

I ask because I'm seeing a bug in my code where setting the `avcodec_context->max_b_frames` value with some codecs is causing a core dump when attempting to use the "flv" codec because FLV doesn't support B Frames

Comment: No, also flv DOES support B frames (assumeing h.264 codec)

Comment: flv codec in flv container. The codec doesn't seem to support b frames

Comment: The flv codec is vp6.

Comment: which features?

Comment: Whether the codec supports B Frames is one example of a feature that I might be interested in